# Get return object with relational data using eager loading

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

I know that I can get object after save method call. But how can I get relational data using eager loading. So that I dont have to give a call to DB for each relation.

Comment: Can you show the code for your controller method and also what relationship you want to load?

Comment: Did you make model for each table?

Comment: I am sorry if you didnt get my question. I am asking that when we save any record using elequoent then it return us that object with the record. I want that record but with all the relational data. Like if I save an item then elequoent by default will return the item data but i want all the images data with that item object but using "eager loading" not with "lazy loading", although I know that I can get it easily with the lazy loading by doing $item->attachments. I want to save my DB calls because I want multiple join records of that item right away after saving that item.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`with()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) method to eager load relations:

```
$collection = Model::with('relation')->get();
```

Then you'll be able to iterate over collections to get objects:

```
@foreach ($collection as $object)
    {{ $object->name }}

    @foreach ($object->relation as $relatedObject)
        {{ $relatedObject->name }}
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Comment: I am sorry if you didnt get my question. I am asking that when we save any record using elequoent then it return us that object with the record. I want that record but with all the relational data. Like if I save an item then elequoent by default will return the item data but i want all the images data with that item object but using "eager loading" not with "lazy loading", although I know that I can get it easily with the lazy loading by doing $item->attachments. I want to save my DB calls because I want multiple join records of that item right away after saving that item.